# Can I specify an NSURLCache for a specific UIWebView or NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, cocoa, caching, webview, nsurlconnection

Is there any way I could specify certain to use a different NSURLCache? My application is dealing with potentially private information. I would like to keep multiple caches so that I can clear the private cache more frequently than the default sharedCache.

I've seen the `[NSURLCache setSharedCache]` method, but I'm wondering if there is a way set a cache webview to webview or request to request.

Any input/feedback/discussion would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: did you figure out if it's possible? I would love to have that in my app as well

Comment: No I have yet to find a solid answer. Most info I read was leading me to believe I'd have to overwrite the entire mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is callback in NSURLConnectionDataDelegate that may help.

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse;
```

connection:willCacheResponse: gives the delegate an opportunity to inspect and modify the                     NSCachedURLResponse which will be cached by the loader if caching is enabled for the original                     NSURLRequest.  Returning nil from this delegate will prevent the resource from being cached.

Note that the -data method of the cached response may return an autoreleased in-memory copy of the true
 data, and should not be used as an alternative to receiving and accumulating the data through connection:didReceiveData:

Comment: I can see where you mean this method would be useful.I would have to use my own cacheing mechanism and drop the cachedURLResponse into different buckets. Seems do-able. I don't think this applies to the UIWebView though